# Joining subplots into a single plot in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

So I have the current function that gives me a plot with a circle and a point at the center of the given circle:

```
def epicentral_distance(station, differential_time_variable, Vp = 5.5, Vs = 3.2):
    ri = differential_time_variable*(1/Vs - 1/Vp)**(-1)
    print( np.round(ri,3) )
    return np.round(ri,3)


def station_earthquake_GraphFunction(station,differential_time_variable, Vp = 5.5, Vs = 3.2):
    radius = epicentral_distance(station, differential_time_variable, Vp = 5.5, Vs = 3.2)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (5,5))

    graph_station = plt.plot(station[0],station[1],'^r')
    graph_circle = plt.Circle(station, radius, color = 'r',fill = False)

    ax.add_artist(graph_circle)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(-100,100,20))
    plt.yticks(np.arange(-100,100,20))
    return graph_station, graph_circle
```

I am trying to run the function with these values:

```
station_earthquake_GraphFunction((10,10), 3.922)
station_earthquake_GraphFunction((15,45),3.272)
station_earthquake_GraphFunction((60,30),3.874)
```

Two questions here:

1. each time I run the function, I get a separate plot. I want to run the function a few times and have the results plotted on a single graph. How would I do that?
2. After running this function 3 times, I will have 3 circles intersecting at a given point. How can I determine the x and y values of the intersection?

Comment: Each call to plt.subplots makes a new figure.  Suggest you call that outside the function and pass ax in as a parameter

Comment: @JodyKlymak So moving the plt.subplots outside definitely gave me what I wanted, however, I don't understand how to pass ax as a parameter. Would you mind explaining that part?

Comment: `station_earthquake((10, 10), 3.92, ax)`?  Obviously you’ll have to change the function as well